# Prove that a simple graph $G$ has a spanning tree such as $G - E(T)$ is disconnected. ($E(T)$ are the edges of the spanning tree).

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to make the proof above. What I've thought so far is that if $T$ is a spanning tree, each other edge the $e$ that is not in $E(T)$ completes a cycle and when we remove all edges from $E(T)$ we remain with a graph of pieces of cycles, wich I believe, but don't know how to prove, are disconnected. Am I going in the right way to make this proof. Any help on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your thoughts indicate that you're trying to show that *every* spanning tree $T$ will leave $G-E(T)$ disconnected. That's false. Instead, you should be thinking about how to choose $T$. A good starting example is the complete graph $K_n$; what spanning tree $T$ should you choose here to leave $K_n - E(T)$ disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more hints. If the graph is not connected, then it has no spanning tree. For connected graphs you can reason like this.

1. Let's choose some tree $S$ from $G$ so that $G-E(S)$ is disconnected (for example, as @Misha Lavrov hints, we can take $S$ so that $V(S)=N(v)+v$ and $E(S)=\{vx\mid x\in N(v)\}$, where $N(v)$ is all neighbors of $v$.)
2. Any tree $S$ of connected graph $G$ can be expanded to a spanning tree $T$ of $G$. (If $V(S)<V(G)$, then there exists a vertex $x\notin V(S)$ and an edge $xy$, where $y\in V(S)$. Now we can extend $S$ to a new tree $S'$, $V(S')=S+x$, $E(S')=E(S)+xy$.)